# Prevent spelling suggestions from being inserted in text messages

Tags: sms, text-input

In text messaging, I noticed that whenever I try to enter a word different from the spelling suggestions, the latter prevail and my intention is ignored. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Which keyboard are you using? If it is google keyboard then go to the app settings -->  text correction. Now uncheck Auto-correction and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Devin who gave me the idea, I went to Settings -> Language & input-> Xperia keyboard -> Word suggestions -> "I never want to have any words or letters replaced".

Answer (score 0):

**In Android 4.1 jelly bean and above:**

> Settings > Language & input > 'choose your keyboard'

Now you will see Options like `Text correction` or `Input` depending on the keyboard you are using. And inside it, you will have options to toggle auto correction.

P.S: Another thing i found annoying is the Spell checker, leaving a red underline while you are typing. You can disable it by:

> Settings > Language & input > Spell checker > 'toggle it off'